# does laravel do some process with the data returned in controllers before send?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a issue with the response time when load a lot of information (laravel models) with some relations, i am debugging, and the process of get the data from database take a litle bit of time, but when the response of controller is sent,  it take more time and i dont know what is the problem, im doing some wrong?

First I thought that sending a lot of data in response could generate an increase in time, so I leaked the data and sent only what was necessary, this improved the time, but only a few seconds,

```php
$start = microtime(true);

$current_user = $this->getCurrentUser();

//Getting data from database
$data = myFunction($current_user);

$time_elapsed_secs = microtime(true) - $start;
dd($time_elapsed_secs); //logs 2 seconds;

return data; // but when i return data, it takes about 50 seconds 
             // in reaching the browser
```

Comment: Are you using VirtualBox or something similar with a "shared" file-system?  I noticed that the shared file-system was causing upwards of 900ms of latency for me.

Comment: I am using docker, but i have 2 environments, una with shared file sistem and other without, but i have the same problem in both